# How to output linked list data in size order?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

I have been given an assignment where a Linked List must print the name of the country and its population by the size.

The linked list and class were provided by the tutor, however as we have not covered much of this I am struggling to understand how to actually get this to work!

So far from reading on here and other sources I have managed to get this far for now, not sure if I'm on the right track honestly. But I am completely lost on how to organise and print the linked list! I am unsure how to define the nodes as the listed items.

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

    def toString(self):
        countries = "{name}: {population}".format(name = self.label, population = self.value)
        if tail is not None:
            nextValue = set.tail.toString()
            countries = "{}, {}".format(countries, nextValue)
            return myValue

    def add_node(self, n): #Adding node function within the list.
        n.set_next(self.root)
        self.root = n
        self.size += 1

    def listSorting(self):
        if self.size > 1:
            newlist = []
            current = self.root
            newlist.append(self.root)
            while current.has_next():
                current = current.get_next()
                newlist.append(current)
            newlist = sorted(newlist, key = lambda node: node.get_data(), reverse = True);
            Linked = LinkedList()
            for node in newlist:
                Linked.add_node(node)
            return

    countries = LinkedList([("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928),("Mauritius",1265985),("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026),("British Virgin Islands (UK)",30030),("Malta",493559),("Greenland (Denmark)",56081),("Guernsey (UK)",62792),("Ethiopia",98665000),("Suriname",581372),("Turkmenistan",6031187),("American Samoa (US)",56700),("French Polynesia (France)",275918),("Equatorial Guinea",1358276),("Solomon Islands",680806),("Burundi",10953317),("Abkhazia",244832),("Rwanda",12374397),("Iceland",364260),("Monaco",38300),("Namibia",2458936),("United States",329532925),("Brazil",211402908),("Finland",5527573),("Armenia",2957500),("Wallis and Futuna (France)",11700),("Cuba",11209628),("Guyana",782766),("Oman",4664790),("Aruba (Netherlands)",112309),("Nauru",11000),("Sri Lanka",21803000),("Myanmar",54339766),("United Arab Emirates",9890400),("Hungary",9772756),("Norfolk Island (Australia)",1756),("Cambodia",15288489),("Fiji",884887),("Benin",11733059),("Egypt",100264508),("Northern Cyprus",351965),("Angola",31127674),("Barbados",287025),("Trinidad and Tobago",1363985),("Colombia",49395678),("Turks and Caicos Islands (UK)",41369),("Norway",5367580),("Kiribati",120100),("Kosovo",1795666),("Azerbaijan",10067108),("Romania",19405156),("Kyrgyzstan",6533500),("Peru",32131400),("Australia",25680766),("Faroe Islands (Denmark)",52124),("Turkey",83154997),("Georgia",3723464),("Singapore",5703600),("Eswatini",1093238),("Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",110608),("East Timor",1387149),("Tuvalu",10200),("Pakistan",219313520),("Bahrain",1543300),("Paraguay",7152703),("Jersey (UK)",106800),("Slovakia",5456362),("Mongolia",3313049),("Argentina",44938712),("Jordan",10660256),("Saint BarthÃ©lemy (France)",9793),("Andorra",77543),("Bangladesh",168456310),("Saint Martin (France)",35746),("FS Micronesia",104468),("South Sudan",12778250),("Artsakh",148000),("Slovenia",2094060),("Senegal",16209125),("Ivory Coast",25823071),("Syria",17500657),("Montserrat (UK)",4989),("Philippines",108505959),("Laos",7123205),("Gibraltar (UK)",33701),("Iran",83371987),("Bahamas",385340),("Mauritania",4077347),("Portugal",10276617),("Madagascar",26251309),("Malawi",19129952),("Central African Republic",5496011),("Saint Kitts and Nevis",52823),("Ghana",30280811),("Honduras",9158345),("Belarus",9408400),("India",1361140893),("Estonia",1328360),("Nicaragua",6460411),("Mali",20250833),("Zambia",17885422),("S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 and Pr\u00edncipe",201784),("Cura\u00e7ao (Netherlands)",158665),("Jamaica",2726667),("Northern Mariana Islands (US)",56200),("Vanuatu",304500),("Kuwait",4420110),("Cameroon",26545864),("Netherlands",17456281),("Saudi Arabia",34218169),("Dominican Republic",10358320),("Japan",125950000),("Djibouti",1078373),("Antigua and Barbuda",96453),("Morocco",35871167),("Nigeria",206139587),("Iraq",39127900),("South Korea",51780579),("Pitcairn Islands (UK)",50),("US Virgin Islands (US)",104578),("Ireland",4921500),("Sierra Leone",7901454),("Cyprus",875900),("Palestine",4976684),("Luxembourg",626108),("Falkland Islands (UK)",3198),("France",67076000),("Bolivia",11469896),("Panama",4218808),("Seychelles",97625),("Guinea-Bissau",1604528),("Puerto Rico (US)",3193694),("Anguilla (UK)",14869),("Macau (China)",679600),("North Macedonia",2077132),("Saint Helena, Ascension",5633),("Sweden",10338368),("Kazakhstan",18683712),("China",1402247960),("Italy",60238522),("Israel",9186750),("Uzbekistan",34131625),("Guam (US)",172400),("Dominica",71808),("Malaysia",32752760),("New Zealand",4978784),("Cape Verde",550483),("Uruguay",3518552),("Belgium",11524454),("Kenya",47564296),("Saint Pierre and Miquelon (France)",6008),("Uganda",40299300),("Yemen",29825968),("Nepal",29996478),("Switzerland",8603899),("Sint Maarten (Netherlands)",40614),("Tonga",100651),("Algeria",43000000),("Haiti",11577779),("Zimbabwe",15159624),("North Korea",25450000),("Congo",5518092),("Belize",408487),("Czech Republic",10693939),("Poland",38379000),("San Marino",33574),("Tanzania",55890747),("Tokelau (NZ)",1400),("Saint Lucia",178696),("Cook Islands (NZ)",15200),("Mozambique",30066648),("Indonesia",266911900),("Grenada",112003),("Burkina Faso",20870060),("Western Sahara",582463),("New Caledonia (France)",282200),("Albania",2845955),("Greece",10724599),("Bosnia and Herzegovina",3301000),("Montenegro",622359),("Russia",146745098),("Samoa",200874),("Comoros",873724),("United Kingdom",66435550),("Taiwan",23604265),("Vatican City",799),("Austria",8902600),("Lebanon",6825442),("Latvia",1906800),("Mexico",126577691),("Venezuela",32219521),("Papua New Guinea",8935000),("Chad",16244513),("Canada",37996639),("Maldives",374775),("Denmark",5822763),("Tajikistan",9127000),("Isle of Man (UK)",83314),("Afghanistan",32225560),("Germany",83149300),("Vietnam",96208984),("Eritrea",3497117),("Spain",47100396),("Costa Rica",5058007),("Cayman Islands (UK)",65813),("Niger",22314743),("Liechtenstein",38749),("Gambia",2347706),("Hong Kong (China)",7500700),("Sudan",42432665),("Tunisia",11722038),("\u00c5land Islands (Finland)",29885),("DR Congo",89561404),("Bulgaria",6951482),("Liberia",4475353),("Botswana",2338851),("Palau",17900),("Niue (NZ)",1520),("Thailand",66494417),("South Africa",58775022),("Lithuania",2793471),("Gabon",2172579),("Libya",6871287),("Transnistria",469000),("Moldova",2681735),("South Ossetia",53532),("Guinea",12218357),("El Salvador",6486201),("Croatia",4076246),("Qatar",2747282),("Serbia",6963764),("Togo",7538000),("Ecuador",17466864),("Cocos (Keeling) Islands (Australia)",538),("Chile",19107216),("Bermuda (UK)",64027),("Somalia",15893219),("Bhutan",741672),("Marshall Islands",55500)])

print(countries)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. Everything you posted was given by the tutor? And you only have to print the list?

Comment: My mistake bud, no. The teacher provided the countries = LinkedList and all the details plus the class linked list. The rest is me. But yes it needs printing in sized order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def print_list(self):
    root, nodes = self, []
    while root:
        nodes.append((root.label, root.value))
        root = root.tail
    nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x[1])
    for node in nodes:
        print(f'{node[0]}: {node[1]}')
```

And call this method

```
countries.print_list()
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall try now :)

Comment: You absolute saint! I've been racking my brain on this all day... thank you so damn much.

Answer (score 0):

The LinkedList is a recursively build object. So let's recursively retrieve its values:

```
def printll(ll):
    print(ll.label, ll.value)
    if ll.tail:
        printll(ll.tail)
    else:
        return


ll = LinkedList(data)
printll(ll)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to be a nuisance but how would I go about adapting into my code or just as it is? Trying to break down the scripts as I go as I learn better this way.